# Getting page details from Facebook account using App Access Token

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am stuck into a problem for which I have not found any solution or documentation.
I am building an app using Facebook API in which user will create an app and will give their APP ID & APP SECRET to the application in order to create pages or post to pages.

Now the problem is they will only login into my application not in facebook nor login using FB.

I am getting APP ACCESS TOKEN from APP ID & APP SECRET.
Using https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials  
 
But how could i use it to get pages for that account or generate USER ACCESS TOKEN from it?

Please help me with your expert guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create Apps nor Pages by using the Graph API! See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page

If you want to publish to a Page the logged-in User administrers, you can request the respective Page Access Token (with `publish_actions` and `manage_pages` permissions!) via

```
GET /me/accounts
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/accounts/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Answer (score 0):

first of create developer apps and get token give some permission

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var url = "http://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth/?scope=user_friends,read_friendlists,read_stream,read_insights,manage_pages,user_checkins,user_photos,read_mailbox,manage_notifications,read_page_mailboxes,email,user_videos,user_groups,offline_access,publish_actions,manage_pages&client_id=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"] + "&redirect_uri=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"] + "&response_type=code";
        return Redirect(url);
    }
```

that automatic redirect call back url for example

```
    public ActionResult AddFacebookAccount(string code)
    {
        string ret = string.Empty;
        string client_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
        string redirect_uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"];
        string client_secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecretKey"];
        long friendscount = 0;
        try
        {
            FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();
            string profileId = string.Empty;
            Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            parameters.Add("client_id", client_id);
            parameters.Add("redirect_uri", redirect_uri);
            parameters.Add("client_secret", client_secret);
            parameters.Add("code", code);
            JsonObject fbaccess_token = null;
            try
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                fbaccess_token = (JsonObject)fb.Get("/oauth/access_token", parameters);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                try
                {
                    fbaccess_token = (JsonObject)fb.Get("/oauth/access_token", parameters);
                }
                catch (Exception ex1)
                {
                    ViewBag.acc_tkn= "issue_access_token";
                }
            }
            string accessToken = fbaccess_token["access_token"].ToString();
            Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;
            if (accessToken != null)
            {
                fb.AccessToken = accessToken;
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                dynamic profile = fb.Get("v2.2/me");
                dynamic friends = fb.Get("v2.2/me/friends");
                try
                {
                    Session["uid"] = profile.id;
                    friendscount = Convert.ToInt16(friends["summary"]["total_count"].ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write(ex.Message);
                }
                ViewBag.acc_tkn = accessToken;
                ViewBag.Uid = profile.id;
            }
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            ViewBag.acc_tkn= "Something Went Wrong";
            return View();
        }
    }
```

you will get access Token  when post data on page refer Bellow Code

```
    public void FacebookPostonPage(string file, string message, string tokenid)
    {
        JsonObject fbaccess_token = null;
        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();
        fb.AccessToken = tokenid;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        fbaccess_token = (JsonObject)fb.Get("v2.0/me/accounts");
        dynamic Result = fbaccess_token["data"];
        foreach (var obj in Result)
        {
            string result = FacebookComposeMessage(obj.access_token, obj.id, message, file);
        }
    }     


    public string FacebookComposeMessage(string tokenid,string userid ,String message,string imagepath)
    {

        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();
        string ret = "";
        fb.AccessToken = tokenid;
        fb.AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
        fb.AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecretKey"];
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        args["message"] = message;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagepath))
        {
            var media = new FacebookMediaObject
            {
                FileName = "filename",
                ContentType = "image/jpeg"
            };
            byte[] img = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imagepath);
            media.SetValue(img);
            args["source"] = media;
            ret = fb.Post("v2.0/" + userid + "/photos", args).ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            ret = fb.Post("v2.0/" + userid + "/feed", args).ToString();
            //   ret = fb.Post("/" + objFacebookAccount.FbUserId + "/photos", args).ToString();
           // var data = fb.Get("v2.2" + ret);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

You will post Successfully try now